# In graph-tool, how could I mask a subgraph?

Tags: python, graph-tool

I create two graph via `graph-tool` library:

```
g1 = graph(directed=False)
g2 = graph(directed=False)
g3 = graph(directed=False)
```

Then:

```
ug = graph_union(g1, g2)
ug = graph_union(ug, g3)
```

If I want to mask `g3` and `g2` in `ug`, how to do?